# Creating a relation out of two ForeignKeys in the same model

Tags: django, django-models

In the example below, if I create a Role, how can I make it that this Role automatically updates Member.band with the band and member values specified in that Role. Currently I have to remember to add that implicit relation manually in admin.

**models.py**

```py
class Band(models.Model):
    pass

class Member(models.Model):
    band = models.ManyToManyField(Band)

class Role(models.Model):
    band = models.ForeignKey(Band)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it in admin only then you can override the [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method:

```
class RoleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        if not change:
            obj.member.band.add(obj.band)
```

Another option is to use the [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/signals/#post-save) signal.  If this case the code will run outside the admin too:

```
def add_band(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.member.band.add(instance.band)

post_save.connect(add_band, sender=Role, dispatch_uid="add_band")
```